# Random text prefixed to App::environment() for laravel app in production

Tags: laravel, amazon-web-services, laravel-vapor

I have a Laravel web app and I call `App::environment()` in the code to build indexes for elasticsearch. It works fine locally, but in production it seems to have a random string is prepended to the value.

The Laravel web app is running on aws via Laravel vapor

```
called App::environment().
expecting "production"
got "Ep9rE9bZ0fproduction"
```

Comment: Forget the specifics of laravel config caching but is it possible its prefixing the env? Did you run `php artisan config:cache`?

Comment: Thanks for your response. I didn't run `php artisan config:cache`, though I do believe laravel vapor cahces config values as part of the deployment. I don't have this error in my local environment, only in production.